# Uploading and downloading a file in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I want code for uploading and downloading a file in JSP.

Comment: Well, just put a link to the file for the download. I don't get it...

Comment: An explicit MIME-type of application/binary may be needed requiring a JSP-page.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, starting the question with "I want code" doesn't yield much helpful response here. Also see [this](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

As to your actual question/problem "How to upload and download files using JSP?": to start off, to select a file for upload using JSP you need at least a HTML `<input type="file">` element which will display a file browse field. As stated in the [HTML forms spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) you need to set the request method to `POST` and the request encoding to `multipart/form-data` in the parent `<form>` element.

Because the aforementioned request encoding isn't by default supported by the Servlet API, you won't see anything in the request parameter map. To retrieve the uploaded file and the other request parameters, you need to parse the `InputStream` of the `HttpServletRequest` yourself. But fortunately there's a commonly used API which can take the precious and tedious work from your hands: [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). At their homepage you can find lot of code examples and important tips&tricks in the *User Guide* and *Frequently Asked Questions* sections. Read them carefully. Basically you just need to get the `InputStream` from the `FileItem` object and write it to any `OutputStream` to your taste using the usual [Java IO](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) way.

And now downloading the file: create a `Servlet` which takes the file identifier as request parameter or pathinfo and uses the usual Java IO way to read the file into an `InputStream` and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletResponse`. You need to set at least the `Content-Disposition` request header to `attachment` which will show a *Save As* dialogue. Finally just call this `Servlet` in the download link or button.

Good luck and in the future please try to ask the question the smart way. The more effort you put in asking a question, the more you will encourage others to post more code. I've only posted hints instead of "complete code examples" so that you need to work it out yourself.